# TP-Link Wifi slow - Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised

Tags: networking, 18.04

I have a TP-Link TL-WN881ND N300 PCI-E Wireless in my PC with Bionic LTS server.

I noticed in the syslog:

```
Oct 14 00:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 6326.989561] TCP: wlp30s0: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
```

As consequence, doing internet speed tests between my 5 yr old laptop and PC... the PC is about 10Mpbs slower on the same wifi.

Is there anything I can do about this and make the TP-Link faster? A better driver?

from dmesg:

```
root@localhost:/home/one# dmesg | grep -i wifi
[    4.456743] rtl8192ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin
[    4.482943] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
```

Comment: Can you please install the `ethtool` package and then run `sudo ethtool -K wlp30s0 gro off` and see if that improves the situation?

Comment: Ok, ran the command successfully but it didn't improve the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded from Bionic Beaver LTS to Xenial LTS and it fixed both issues. I am no longer getting the message and my speeds are up to what they should be at 32mpbs(10 mpbs faster).